# How to apply transformation to selection in Illustrator by scripting

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I managed to select every thing I want in Illustrator with a ExtendScript Toolkit javascript code: lots of things (text, path, symbols, ...) in several layers. Now I want to resize them the same way, then move them.

I know how to apply a transformation to one object by code, but I want to avoid looping on each element because it would be very very long and transformation would be applied from the anchor point of each element, so my drawings wouldn't be cohesive.

So, I am looking for a way to do like in Illustrator UI: right click > transform > scale. Is there any UI command like this I could access from code  (javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to do this:

1. Record AI Actions that perform required transformations, and then play these Actions (by `DoScript`) from your script
2. Group selected objects and apply required transformations to the group as @Dane proposed.  You need to backup the `Layer` object property to allow objects to be restored in original layers, as shown in VBA example below:

   ```
   For i = Index_Lo To Index_Hi
       Call Layers_Backup.Add(Item:=SelectedItems(i).Layer, Key:=Format(i))
       Call SelectedItems(i).Move(Temp_Group, AiElementPlacement.aiPlaceAtEnd)
   Next i

   Call Temp_Group.Resize(scaleX:=120, scaleY:=120, changeLineWidths:=120)

   For i = Index_Lo To Index_Hi
       Call SelectedItems(i).Move(Layers_Backup(Format(i)), AiElementPlacement.aiPlaceAtEnd)
   Next i
   ```
3. Call Windows API functions (like `PostMessage (..., WM_COMMAND, ..., ...)`, `SendDlgItemMessage`, `FindWindowEx` etc) to show, fill and execute  required AI transformations dialog boxes

IMHO, item #1 is the easiest to implement while item#2 is the most reliable

Answer (score 0):

So I dont know if you can get away with not looping in some form or other. that said, if you dont mind putting your selection in to a group, it might be faster to loop through your selection adding to a group which might be faster than looping and through the selection and scale and moving each element. With the group object you can then do *groupObject*.scale() and .translate().
Here is a snippet i took from a script of mine.

```
#target "illustrator"
var aiApp = app.activeDocument;
var aSelection = aiApp.selection;
var aGroup = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();

for (i=0; i < aSelection.length; i++){
aSelection[i].move( aGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE); 
aSelection[i].move( aGroup, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);  
 }
//moves up 700 points and scales by 200
aGroup.translate(0,700)
aGroup.resize(200, 200, true , true, true, true, 200)
```

Comment: Very good idea to group my selection. Transformations are easier when everything is grouped. However, I need to keep things in layers because layer names are important.