# Trying to create an illustrator script to fill color what is selected and export it for each color in a swatch group

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, jsx, adobe-illustrator

As the title says, I have pieced together and written my own code into this monstrosity you see below.  It has been a good three years since I have done any coding and my main job is graphic design so please excuse the sloppy coding job.  What I am trying to accomplish is having the script run through the swatches and apply the fill color to what is selected on the sreen and then export a .png file for each color with the file name as the color of the swatch.

Everything seems to be working with the script except it is not applying the fill color.  It will export and even rename the file for each color in the swatch group but they all export the same default color so I do not believe that the selection is being filled.  Can anyone instruct me on what I have wrong in my code?  If I can get this code to work, it will transform an unreasonable amount of work into something more manageable.

Thanks!

```
#target illustrator

//get a reference to the the current document

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var mySelection = doc.selection;
var swatches = doc.swatches;

//select a folder to save images into
var savePath = Folder.selectDialog( 'Please select a folder to export swatch images into', '~' );
//exported image dimensions
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
//PNG export options
var pngExportOpts = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
   pngExportOpts.antiAliasing = false;//keep it pixel perfect 
   pngExportOpts.artBoardClipping = false;//use the path's dimensions (setup above), ignore full document size
   pngExportOpts.saveAsHTML = false;
   pngExportOpts.transparency = true;//some swatches might have transparency


//go through the swatches


for(var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++){
   //set the fill colour based on the current swatch colour

   mySelection.fillColor = swatches[i].color;

   //export png
   doc.exportFile( new File( savePath+ '/' + swatches[i].name + '.png'), ExportType.PNG24, pngExportOpts );
   //remove any previous paths (in case of transparent swatches)

   // doc.pathItems.removeAll();
}
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but I see you do `mySelection.fillColor = ...`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809541/1913729) suggests that `mySelection` would be an Array. Could you try replacing this line with `for(var j=0; j<mySelection.length; j++) { mySelection[j].fillColor = swatches[i].color; }` and tell us if it changes anything ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance but it still does not seem to be working as intended.

Comment: Just tried it, it works with a rectangle shape. Can you show us what type of selection you have?

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is here but am still unsure why that is.  It works for a single shape but what I am trying to do is a compound path consisting of many shapes.  Its all the same selection and technically the same shape so I do not understand why it works for one shape but if I copy that shape and select them both then it just exports all the same color without going through the list

Comment: Tried with multiple shapes, got this: https://imgur.com/a/m7J4Cz0 (with the script modified as I proposed above)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I was able to get the code to work with new shapes that I created and expanded but not with ones that I have previously had as line art that I expanded into a shape. For some reason those previously created shapes just do not want to fill when the script runs

Comment: Hello @Mike3123, check this [link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Illustrator/fill-color-using-a-script/td-p/4982314) it has content that can fill compound path.